# cuda kernel is not accessing all the element of an array

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

I have written a cuda program to do some operation on large array. But when I pass that array to a cuda kernel, then all of its elements are not accessed by threads. Below, there is a simple program explaining my use case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__global__
void kernel(int n){
        int s = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
        int t = blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
        for(int i=s;i<n;i+=t){
        printf("%d\n",i);  //printing index of array which is being accessed
        }
}

int main(void){
        int i,n = 10000; //array_size
        int blockSize = 64;
        int numBlocks = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
        kernel<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(n);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

I've tried with different `blockSize = 256, 128, 64, etc`, It is not printing all the indices of array. Ideally, it should print any permutation of `0 to n-1`, however it is printing lesser`(<n)` numbers.

If `numBlocks` and `blockSize` both are 1, then it is accessing all the element. And if array size is less than 4096, then also it is accessing all the elements.

Comment: How are you counting the numbers?

Comment: I piped the output of this program to file then `cat filename | wc -l`

Comment: Consider accepting any of the answers as valid if they helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use better debugging techniques! Your code is properly functional

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

__global__
void kernel(int* in, int n){
    int s = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int t = blockDim.x*gridDim.x;
    for (int i = s; i<n; i += t){
        in[i] = 1;  //printing index of array which is being accessed
    }
}

int main(void){
    int i, n = 10000; //array_size
    int blockSize = 64;
    int numBlocks = (n + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    int* d_res,*h_res;
    cudaMalloc(&d_res, n*sizeof(int));
    h_res = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    kernel << <numBlocks, blockSize >> >(d_res, n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(h_res, d_res, n*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += h_res[i];
    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Comment: @kayush206 printf  can be a way to debug, but certainly 100000 printf are not a way to debug!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, all of the values are being printed in the current case. but you may not be able to see all of them due to buffer limit of the output console. Try increasing the output console's buffer size.

Additionally, keep in mind that the `printf` calls inside the kernel execute out-of-order. Also, there are limitations of the `printf` buffer on the device which are explained in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations).

Comment: `printf` is out of order, that is fine. But shouldn't it print any permutation of `n` numbers.

Comment: I guess, the buffer is not being completely flushed. As mentioned in the documentation, try calling `cudaDeviceReset()` at the code end.

Comment: `cudaDeviceReset()` didn't help :( again the same issue.

Comment: increasing the output console's buffer size can fix the problem. `cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitPrintfFifoSize, size_t size)` is the necessary API which set the buffer size. buffer size is `1MB` by default.